# data-ajax="false" for for all web pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using j query mobile for my Web Site . My Website dont need any Ajax functionality . I want native page links. But in j query mobile page transfers are in Ajax mode. If we want to turn it off we need to use syntax `data-ajax="false"` where we don't need Ajax.

can we turn off ajax for whole website

Note : I use include pages for PHP  so any common code will work for all pages

Comment: `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `mobileInit` event, pass `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` to disable ajax for mobile page navigation:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Proper format for binding your `mobileInit` event:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.js"></script>
```

1. jQuery core specific
2. `mobileInit` event handler
3. the jQuery Mobile js file

**jQuery mobile js file is last so the event handler `mobileInit` will be set before any event is fired**.

Reference: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: it will disale ajax for form post also ?

Comment: @ddw147 yup, everything.

Comment: Yes it will. Previous `ajaxFormsEnabled = false;` option is not listed as config default anymore.